# How can I concat two dataframes when index doesn't match but length does?

Tags: python, pandas

I went through the docs and I can't seem to get this to work. I have two dataframes:

```
results
    alpha   beta
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
3   0.000498    0.229398
4   0.000566    0.247263
... ... ...
2172    -0.000011   0.047709
2173    -0.000072   0.097026
2174    -0.000152   0.136203
2175    -0.000231   0.162171
2176    -0.000336   0.189575
2177 rows × 2 columns

pricedataDFpivot
ticker  GSPC.INDX   IBM.US  US10Y.INDX  adjustedRF  index_returns   equity_returns  excess_market_returns
date                            
2013-01-02  1462.609771 194.142211  1.887720    0.000748    0.000288    -0.004194   -0.000464
2013-01-03  1462.855211 194.051868  1.886930    0.000747    0.000347    -0.003932   -0.000404
2013-01-04  1463.206667 193.952563  1.885795    0.000747    0.000423    -0.003625   -0.000327
2013-01-07  1463.938459 193.770398  1.883490    0.000746    0.000575    -0.003045   -0.000174
2013-01-08  1464.988717 193.592202  1.880311    0.000745    0.000763    -0.002364   0.000017
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-05-28  4199.212610 144.565649  1.594406    0.000631    0.000779    0.002077    0.000148
2021-06-01  4201.940726 144.761351  1.593903    0.000631    0.000881    0.002887    0.000251
2021-06-02  4203.861359 144.954979  1.593812    0.000631    0.000999    0.003651    0.000368
2021-06-03  4204.773694 145.060406  1.593861    0.000631    0.001065    0.004065    0.000434
2021-06-04  4205.446075 145.156847  1.593955    0.000631    0.001132    0.004426    0.000501
2177 rows × 7 columns
```

but when I try to contact them it doesn't look right:

```
    pd.concat([pricedataDFpivot, results], axis=1)
    GSPC.INDX   IBM.US  US10Y.INDX  adjustedRF  index_returns   equity_returns  excess_market_returns   alpha   beta
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-05-28 00:00:00.000000000   4198.215778 144.581490  1.595192    0.000632    0.000806    0.002109    0.000175    NaN NaN
2021-06-01 00:00:00.000000000   4201.047538 144.744895  1.594335    0.000631    0.000885    0.002793    0.000255    NaN NaN
2021-06-02 00:00:00.000000000   4203.046893 144.899846  1.593987    0.000631    0.000971    0.003421    0.000341    NaN NaN
2021-06-03 00:00:00.000000000   4204.005464 144.983396  1.593883    0.000631    0.001020    0.003757    0.000389    NaN NaN
2021-06-04 00:00:00.000000000   4204.693709 145.057410  1.593876    0.000631    0.001066    0.004047    0.000435    NaN NaN
4354 rows × 9 columns
```

it added more columns. When I remove axis=1, it still adds column.

I've tried ignore_index=True but it has the same effect but I lose the column names.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the number of rows are the same so I'm just trying to line up both dataframes.

What can I do to get the expected output, which is the data in results lined up with the data in pricedataDFpivot? Basically 2177 rows of both dataframes just lined up(they are in the right order right now).

Comment: What should the result look like instead?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I updated the answer to show it. I just want the two data frame lined up. My above command

Comment: `df2.assign(**{col: df1[col].to_numpy() for col in df1})` using underlying values to ignore index

Comment: or you can try `df1.reset_index()`, then `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add new columns to your dataframe:

```
pricedataDFpivot[['alpha', 'beta']] = results[['alpha', 'beta']].values
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to concat horizontally

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    { 'A' : [1111,2222,3333,1111,2222,3333],
      'B' : ['A','Y','Z','A','B','C'] } )

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    { 'E' : [13.5,45.5,78.9,1.23,4.56,7.81] } )

pd.concat([df1, df2.set_index(df1.index)], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
       A    B   E
0   1111    A   13.50
1   2222    Y   45.50
2   3333    Z   78.90
3   1111    A   1.23
4   2222    B   4.56
5   3333    C   7.81
```

Note:

If the indexes are different you should

Comment: It worked because your 2 df share the same index. Before concat, try df2.index += 10. Use **`set_index`** and not `reindex`. Please fixed.

Comment: Oh nice catch. Thank you. This could work as well: 
```df2.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)``` before concat. I fixed it.